# Improve my $(\epsilon, \delta)$ proof of absolute value function continuity

Tags: inequality, continuity, solution-verification, absolute-value, epsilon-delta

In Charles C. Pugh's Real Mathematical Analysis [2nd Ed] on page 76, continuity of $f : x \mapsto \lvert x \rvert$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is a corollary of another theorem. However, I wanted to see if I could use the $(\epsilon, \delta)$-condition to prove its continuity. My proof below seems overly complicated; if you can find any ways to improof it, please let me know!

---

**Conclusion.** We want to show that for any $\epsilon > 0$ and any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that if $y \in \mathbb{R}$ then the following holds:
$$ \lvert y - x \vert < \delta \implies \bigl\lvert |y| - |x| \bigr\rvert < \epsilon , $$
i.e., $\lvert * \rvert$ is continuous.

**Proof.** Choose $\delta := \epsilon$. We want to show that $\bigl\lvert |y| - |x| \bigr\rvert \leq \lvert y - x \vert < \delta = \epsilon$. There are 8 cases to consider:

1. $|y| > |x|$
   a) $y > 0, x > 0$
   b) $y > 0, x < 0$
   c) $y < 0, x > 0$
   d) $y < 0, x < 0$
2. The same four cases but with $|x| < |y|$.

Without loss of generality, we prove case 1. For each sub-case, $|y| > |x|$ implies $|y| - |x| > 0$, so $\bigl\lvert |y| - |x| \bigr\rvert = |y| - |x|$.

**1.a)** Note that $y - x > 0$. Hence

$$ \bigl\lvert |y| - |x| \bigr\rvert = y - x = | y - x | . $$

**1.b)** Note that since $x < 0$, we have $y + x < y - x$. Note also that $y - x > 0$. Hence

$$ \bigl\lvert |y| - |x| \bigr\rvert = y - (-x) = y + x < y - x = | y - x | . $$

**1.c)** Note that since $x > 0$, we have $-y + x > -y - x$. Note also that $x - y > 0$. Hence

$$ \bigl\lvert |y| - |x| \bigr\rvert = -y - x < x - y = | x - y | = | y - x |. $$

**1.d)** Note that since $-y < -x$ we have $x - y < 0$. Hence

$$ \bigl\lvert |y| - |x| \bigr\rvert = -y - (-x) = x - y < |x - y| = | y - x | . $$

Therefore all cases satisfy $\bigl\lvert |y| - |x| \bigr\rvert \leq \lvert y - x \vert < \epsilon$, as required.

---

I think it is possible to structure the proof so that, using symmetry, only two cases need to be proved.

Comment: Hint: $|y-x| \geq |y|-|x|$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's show that

$$
||x|-|y|| \leq |x-y|
$$

for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Indeed, by the triangle inequality, we have
\begin{align}
|x| &= |x - y + y| \\
&\leq |x-y| + |y|,
\end{align}
which implies $|x| - |y| \leq |x-y|$. Exchanging $x$ and $y$ leads to $|y| - |x| \leq |x-y|$. Hence, the inequality is established. Can you simplify your proof from here?

Comment: Multiplying by -1,
$$ |y| - |x| \leq |x - y| \implies |x| - |y| \geq -|x-y| , $$
and the result follows.

Comment: $|y| = |y - x + x| \leq |y - x| + |x|$, which can be rewritten as $|y| - |x| \leq |x-y|$.